# How to achieve the following requirement using sql query

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

```
  TABLE1               TABLE2
ID   DATE             ID   NAME
1    1 JAN            1    ABC
2    2 JAN            2    ABC
3    3 JAN            3    CDF
4    4 JAN            4    CDF
```

do the grouping on table2 so that id=1,2 and 3,4 will form 2 groups since 1,2 has NAME as ABC and so on. This 2 sets with id=1,2 and 3,4 will be joined with TABLE1 with id as the common factor to search min date among id=1,2 and id=3,4
so that the end result should be like:

```
ID   DATE    
1   1 JAN 
3   3 JAN
```

[image]

Comment: You're almost there. Simply JOIN and GROUP BY. (No stored procedure needed.)

Answer (score 0):

One way, using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t1.ID, t1.DATE,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.NAME ORDER BY t2.ID) rn
    FROM TABLE1 t1
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2
        ON t1.ID = t2.ID
)

SELECT ID, DATE
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use simply join

```
select t1.id,t1.date from
 table1 t1 join
(select min(ID) as id,name from
 table2
 group by name
) t2
  on t1.id=t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You would normally do this with a `join` and `group by`:

```
select t2.name, min(t2.date)
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
group by t2.name;
```

Such a query requires neither a subquery nor a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

You want one result row per name, so group by name:

```
select
  min(t2.id) as id,
  min(t1.date) as date
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
group by t2.name
order by min(t2.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jQcjKCYe41x6T75CH8xtou/0)

```
select id, date
  from table1
 where dt in (select min(date)
                from table1 A
                     left join table2 B
                            on A.id = B.id
               group by name)
```